# Python: how to open a file using system app on Android

Tags: python, android, kivy

**The goal is top open a file in Android's default app**

For example, an image in Gallery

**The file path is known**.

I've searched a lot but could not find any answer.

(I am making a `kivy app` and then building an `apk` using `Buildozer`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution,

https://github.com/kivy/plyer/issues/500#issuecomment-565532048

This uses Fileprovider and pyjnius